# Dar un color diferente a cada jugador cuando se conecte

Tags: nodejs, express, socket.io

Estoy haciendo un proyecto el cual consiste en un minijuego multijugador con **Node**, **Express** y **Socket.io** en el que cada jugador tiene un color diferente que le asigna el servidor al entrar y los jugadores verán una tabla la cual los jugadores tienen que ir pintando las celdas y al final quien haya pintado mas celdas gana.

Mi problema esta en que al primer jugador que entra le asigno el color rojo por ejemplo, al segundo que entra le asigno el verde pero ahora el jugador que era rojo también es de color verde, si entra otro mas será azul pero el resto de jugadores también serán de color azul y así sucesivamente.

¿Como puedo hacer que cada jugador tenga su color y no se actualice cuando entra otro jugador? Gracias de antemano.

**Servidor**

```
var id=1;
var colorhexadecimal;

io.on('connection', function(socket){
console.log("user"+id+" connected");

colorhexadecimal = "";

if(id==1){
  colorhexadecimal = "orange";
}else if(id==2){
  colorhexadecimal = "green";
}else if(id==3){
  colorhexadecimal = "red";
}else if(id==4){
  colorhexadecimal = "purple";
}else {
colorhexadecimal = "";
}

id++;

io.emit('colorEvent', colorhexadecimal);

socket.on('pintar', function(id){
 io.emit('pintar', id);
});

socket.on('disconnect', function () {
 console.log('A user disconnected');
});
```

**Cliente**

```
$(function () {
  var socket = io();

  socket.on('colorEvent', function(colorhexadecimal){ 
    color = colorhexadecimal;
  });

  $('.celda').click(function(event){
    var idRecibida = event.target.id;
    socket.emit('pintar',idRecibida);
    return false;
  });

  socket.on('pintar', function(id){ 
    $('#'+id).css("background-color", color);
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando haces un `io.emit()` lo que haces es notificar a todos los clientes conectados, lo que debes hacer es enviar el emit solo al cliente que se acaba de conectar no a todos cambia, el `io.emit()` por `socket.emit()`, por otra parte si tus colores ya son definidos, insertarlos en un arreglo y solo accedes a la posición del arreglo en vez de usar tantos if

```js
var id=1;
const colors = ['','orange','green','red','purple'];

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log("user"+id+" connected"); 
  if(id >=1 && id<= 4 ){
    colorhexadecimal = colors[id];
  } else {
    colorhexadecimal = colors[0];
  }
  id++;

  socket.emit('colorEvent', colorhexadecimal);

  socket.on('pintar', function(id){
   socket.emit('pintar', id);
  });

  socket.on('disconnect', function () {
   console.log('A user disconnected');
  });
});
```

Comment: El problema era el que indicabas el **io.emit()** y el **socket.emit()** no sabia la diferencia entre ellos. Gracias también por el arreglo con los "if"